# How can i disable playframework's reverse routing?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I would like to disable reverse routing in playframework. How do i do that?

**Note**: I am using Play! 2.5.9

I have tried the following:

```
PlayKeys.generateRefReverseRouter := false
```

And then I get the following error:

```
error: value generateRefReverseRouter is not a member of object 
play.sbt.Play.autoImport.PlayKeys
PlayKeys.generateRefReverseRouter := false
         ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I also tried setting:

```
RoutesKeys.generateReverseRouter := false
```

Which generates the following error:

```
ERROR: object RoutesPrefix is not a member of package router
```

Answer (score 2):

For 2.5.x `RoutesKeys` is in `play.sbt.routes._`. Check the [mainline](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/routes/RoutesCompiler.scala)

The following works for me in 2.5.9 (`build.sbt`):-

```
import play.sbt.routes._

RoutesKeys.generateReverseRouter := false
```

Comment: Nio - thanks for replying. I tried the exact same thing you suggested but i continue to get the same  error:                                                              [error]  .../conf/routes:15: object RoutesPrefix is not a member of package router

Comment: Your error is telling you that you have declared a route in `/conf/routes` that cannot be resolved, probably because you have disabled the reverse router. What do you have on line 15 in `/conf/routes`?

Comment: I have a very simple route defined on line 15:                                                      GET     /hello                      com.test.controllers.TestController.hello()

Comment: @jesukumar: I have the same error. I'm trying to disable the reverse routing it seems we can't have a route file AND disable the reverse router which make no sense... did you find how to do it?